# runtime automatic restart error in google colab

Tags: python, keras, google-colaboratory

hi i want to use google colab to train a model for my classification but when i start training after a few seconds, it says 'Runtime died. Automatically restarting.'

my model is:

```
model=keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(230, 320, 3)),
    keras.layers.Dense(32,activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(10,activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(5,activation=tf.nn.softmax),
])
opt=tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=opt,metrics=['accuracy'])
```

and training code is :

```
model.fit(train_data,train_labels,epochs=25,validation_split=0.2)
```

any suggestion?

Comment: Please share a self-contained notebook that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so I solved the problem and the error was because  I choosed  one channel of image ,when I choose the 3 channels the problem gone.